# Use of picasa api from Google Photos share link

Tags: picasa, google-photos

I'm currently using the picasa API to display public and private albums of multiple users on my own webpage. To view a picasa album I need a userId, an albumId and optionally an authkey.

I used to get these id's from picasaweb.google.com, but since Google discontinued that service in favour of photos.google.com, I cannot get the id's anymore.

I would like to switch over to `photos.google.com`, but there is no API for `photos.google.com` (yet).

Is there any way, to distill the `userId` and `albumId` from a Google Photos share link (`https:// goo.gl / photos / something`)?